# Geocoding without Google API?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, openlayers, openstreetmap

I cant find a way to convert an adress to a long/lat coordinate **without** using google geocoding API.
Im working with Open Layers and Open Street Map and have to avoid google api because of the 2.500 views/day limitation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should take a look at [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).